# one file is converted to machine code i think, not sure how to revert back to original visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My System switched accidentally and I was doing code. when I started the PC again and opened my project in Visual Studio. I got this

[image: Here]

now when I am writing anything in this file it is in the same format, is in the image. I have done a lot in this file. but didn't commit in after lunch. 
Please suggest, how I can revert it to the original text.

UPDATED :

file is .cshtml (view file) in MVC.

Comment: Any more details? What file is it? What extension? What happened exactly? It looks like you opened the disassembly window.

Comment: That's a file composed solely of nulls, there is no valid data within it if it all looks like that.  Your options are to restore from backup/source control

Comment: JUST CHECKED the file explorer there is another file.. AFBJJAthleteDetails.cshtml~RFa09c70.TMP .....  both files has null null null written in them

Comment: If you have recently run the code, you can look for the binary this got compiled into and use dotPeek or Reflector or similar to extract the compiled version of the page. That will have the basic structure but you'll have to work back from the compiled C# to cshtml yourself sorry.

Comment: You could also try running chkdsk on the off chance it will find an orphaned file that might contain your code. You'll likely have to pick through a lot of them though to find the right one, if it does exist.

Comment: It is not machine code, the file content got destroyed when the machine lost power.  You must restore the file from source control.  This isn't supposed to happen btw, NTFS is a journaling file system designed to prevent exactly this kind of data loss.   There is some kind of anti-malware product or whatnot that turned malicious, I have seen several SO users experience this problem.  But nobody ever tells us what runs on their machine so this is as yet undiagnosed.

Comment: @Rup, i am using Git but this file is just added newly and had a lot work after lunch break. and is not in Git.

Comment: @HansPassant, how can i confirm this. ?

Comment: :-( fair enough. On the plus side it's usually easier to do something the second time around if you do have to start from scratch, but sounds like you're probably out of luck.